# problem with using coalesce to merge 2 columns into 1

Tags: r, merge

I would like to merge values from 2 columns into 1. For example, here is sample data:

```
id   x    y
1   12  
1         14  
2   13      
3   15 
3         18
4         19
```

I want

```
id   x    y     z
1   12          12  
1         14    14  
2   13          13 
3   15          15 
3         18    18
4         19    19
```

I tried using coalesce to create a new variable.

```
coalesce <- function(...) {
  apply(cbind(...), 1, function(x) {
    x[which(!is.na(x))[1]]
  })
}

df$z <- coalesce(df$x, df$y)
```

However, the variable doesn't reflect the columns joined. Am I using this function incorrectly?

Comment: Could you provide the data frame example with `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `dplyr::coalesce` function:

```
> df$z <- dplyr::coalesce(ifelse(df$x == "", NA, df$x), df$y)
> df
  id  x  y  z
1  1 12    12
2  1    14 14
3  2 13    13
4  3 15    15
5  3    18 18
6  4    19 19
>
```

To implement my own `mycoalesce`:

```
mycoalesce <- function(...) {apply(cbind(...), 1, max)}
```

And:

```
> df$z <- mycoalesce(df$x, df$y)
> df
  id  x  y  z
1  1 12    12
2  1    14 14
3  2 13    13
4  3 15    15
5  3    18 18
6  4    19 19
>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a more crude and inefficient way than the other methods posted above, but still worth a try:

```
df1<-df
df1[is.na(df1)]=0
z=df1$x+df1$y
df<-cbind(df,z)
df
#  ID  x  y  z
#1  1 12 NA 12
#2  2 NA 14 14
#3  3 13 NA 13
#4  4 15 NA 15
#5  5 NA 18 18
#6  6 NA 19 19
```

I mainly copied the original dataframe to a new dataframe so as to preserve the `NA` values in the original dataframe. Also, I assumed that none of the `ID`'s are missing along with @Park's assumption.

Data: `df<-data.frame(ID=1:6,x=c(12,NA,13,15,NA,NA),y=c(NA,14,NA,NA,18,19))`

Answer (score 0):

If one of `x` and `y` is always `NA` and one has value,

for a custom function `%+%` defined like

```
`%+%` <- function(x, y)  mapply(sum, x, y, MoreArgs = list(na.rm = TRUE))

df$z <- df$x %+% df$y
df
  id  x  y  z
1  1 12 NA 12
2  1 NA 14 14
3  2 13 NA 13
4  3 15 NA 15
5  3 NA 18 18
6  4 NA 19 19
```

Comment: Thanks @Park. For some reason, the code is resulting in my R version to go into Browser mode.