# How to sort data that is placed in multiple columns into one column?

Tags: r, excel, multiple-columns

I have a dataset in excel with multiple columns that contain one specific set of data that is randomly distributed within these columns. The data looks like this:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6
Data  34    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    Data  32    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    Data  12
NA    Data  89    NA    NA    NA
```

I want to get all the `Data` fields into one column named data, so the data set looks like this (the `NA` columns are not important for now, I have this issue with several fields, so I will need to replicate the solution for other fields as well):

```
Data
34  
32   
12 
89
```

As I am currently working in excel, an easy solution there would be great, however, I will move to R at some point, so a solution in R would also be welcomed!

Thank you very much and sorry for the cryptic description.

Edit: Here is a picture of my real data - in this example I want a column named "Total supply", one named "Ticker" and one named "Accepted Currencies", with the respective data (following the named cell) in the correct column.

[image]

The output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: so just to be clear, in your original data, instead of `NA` there are other values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [problem with using coalesce to merge 2 columns into 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907912/problem-with-using-coalesce-to-merge-2-columns-into-1)

Comment: @starja Yes, exactly

Comment: @Limey unfortunately no, since I have this issue with several columns and multiple data cells so I always want to merge the columns next to the ones that contain "Data"

Answer (score 3):

If your data is in a matrix called `mat`, the following code extracts the desired values into a vector:

```
apply(mat, 1L, \(row) row[which(row == 'Data') + 1L])
# [1] "34" "32" "12" "89"
```

This assumes that the data is correctly formatted. Any divergence will yield unexpected results.

It’s also possible to do this without `apply` using vectorised functions but the resulting code is a bit longer:

```
ind = which(mat == 'Data', arr.ind = TRUE)
ord = order(ind[, 1L])
mat[cbind(seq_along(ord), ind[ord, 2L] + 1L)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

[image]

Formula used in `A6`:

```
=TOCOL(IF(A1:E4="Data",B1:F4,NA()),3)
```

Or, a bit more dynamic:

```
=LET(a,A1:F4,TOCOL(IF(DROP(a,,-1)="Data",DROP(a,,1),NA()),3))
```

---

**EDIT:** Updated answer based on new information;

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=LET(a,TOCOL(A1:D13,3),IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(EXPAND(0,,3),SEQUENCE(ROWS(a-1)),LAMBDA(x,y,LET(b,INDEX(a,y+1),c,FILTER(x,NOT(ISERROR(TAKE(x,,1)))),SWITCH(INDEX(a,y),"Ticker",VSTACK(c,b),"Total Supply",VSTACK(DROP(c,-1),HSTACK(TOROW(TAKE(c,-1),3),b)),"Accepted Currencies",VSTACK(DROP(c,-1),HSTACK(TAKE(c,-1,2),b)),c)))),1),""))
```

Comment: That already helps, thank you - any idea how I can use this if I also have a coupld of empty rows in between? Since my real data set sometimes has a row without "Data" in it, the formula copies the next value directly in that row which I want to avoid, i.e. keep the empty value.

Comment: Do you have a visual example of that @Soph2010?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post and added a picture

Comment: @Soph2010, that's quite a steep increase in difficulty I'm afraid. See if the edited answer does justice to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately not quite, thank you for trying though! There should be an empty cell between F3 and F4

Answer (score 1):

With the example `df` from below, you could do:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
df <- data.frame(Data = c(t(df)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

subset(df, ave(Data, cumsum(is.na(Data)), FUN = length) > 1L & Data != 'Data')
```

Output:

```
   Data
2    34
10   32
18   12
21   89
```

This approach would capture multiple consecutive occurrences of values. You haven't specified whether (and how) potential `NA` values occurring after `Data` should be captured - that would require a modification (e.g. you could capture all the values occurring after each appearance of `Data` in case they contain at least one `non-NA`, or it could be you just wanted to capture single `NA` in case the whole vector afterwards is empty but we've nevertheless `Data`, etc.).

Data:

```
df <- read.table(
  text = 'Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6
Data  34    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    Data  32    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    Data  12
NA    Data  89    NA    NA    NA', header = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Instead of the NAs I have multiple other data fields like the "Data" ones, that I need to capture as well. So basically some fields that have e.g. "Data2" as a text in them and in the cell right next to it the value and then I would like to have a "Data2" column as well. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand, however I think it would be best if you modify your example to resemble your real data well enough. Only then we'll be able to cater for all particular rules and edge cases in our solutions.

Comment: I edited my post to include a picture of the real data and the desired output - does that help?